# How to find user control by its tagname from a UserControl in C#

Tags: c#, webforms, user-controls

I have created a usercontrol (DateRange) for date and used it multiple times in a separate usercontrol. Now on page load I want to iterate through all DateRange usercontrol to get its id.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Report User Controls/DateRange.ascx" TagName="DateRange" TagPrefix="DateRange" %>
<div id="divLOGDate" style="display: none" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updLOGDate" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <DateRange:DateRange ID="LOGDate" runat="server" Visible="false" />
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<div id="divDOBDate" style="display: none" runat="server">
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updDOBDate" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
    <DateRange:DateRange ID="DOBDate" runat="server" Visible="false" />
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```